# How to connect to docker-compose mysql after container has initilized?

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I have a project that I have been working on and now I am experimenting with docker-compose to build it.
Before running my own custom scripts to create tables and such I thought I would just give it a go and see if it builds and I can connect to it.

I found a suitable docker-compose for mysql:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:latest
    ports:
      - 3307:3307
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: SomeRootPassword1!
      MYSQL_USER: someuser
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: Password1!
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wedding
```

After running docker-compose-up in gitbash I see:

```
mysql_1  | 2020-08-26 20:00:14+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.21-1debian10 started.
mysql_1  | 2020-08-26 20:00:14+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
mysql_1  | 2020-08-26 20:00:14+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.21-1debian10 started.
mysql_1  | 2020-08-26 20:00:14+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Initializing database files
mysql_1  | 2020-08-26T20:00:14.502438Z 0 [System] [MY-013169] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.21) initializing of server in progress as process 43
mysql_1  | 2020-08-26T20:00:14.507639Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
mysql_1  | 2020-08-26T20:00:15.519301Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
mysql_1  | 2020-08-26T20:00:17.309017Z 6 [Warning] [MY-010453] [Server] root@localhost is created with an empty password ! Please consider switching off the --initialize-insecure option.
mysql_1  | 2020-08-26 20:00:21+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Database files initialized
mysql_1  | 2020-08-26 20:00:21+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Starting temporary server
mysql_1  | 2020-08-26T20:00:22.149193Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.21) starting as process 90
mysql_1  | 2020-08-26T20:00:22.170767Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
mysql_1  | 2020-08-26T20:00:22.378726Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
mysql_1  | 2020-08-26T20:00:22.457272Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
mysql_1  | 2020-08-26T20:00:22.549270Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
mysql_1  | 2020-08-26T20:00:22.549394Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
mysql_1  | 2020-08-26T20:00:22.553380Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
mysql_1  | 2020-08-26T20:00:22.564741Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.21'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 0  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
mysql_1  | 2020-08-26 20:00:22+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Temporary server started.
mysql_1  | Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/iso3166.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
mysql_1  | Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/leap-seconds.list' as time zone. Skipping it.
mysql_1  | Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
mysql_1  | Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone1970.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
mysql_1  | 2020-08-26 20:00:24+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Creating database wedding
mysql_1  | 2020-08-26 20:00:24+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Creating user someuser
mysql_1  | 2020-08-26 20:00:24+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Giving user someuser access to schema wedding
mysql_1  |
mysql_1  | 2020-08-26 20:00:24+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Stopping temporary server
mysql_1  | 2020-08-26T20:00:24.697408Z 14 [System] [MY-013172] [Server] Received SHUTDOWN from user root. Shutting down mysqld (Version: 8.0.21).
mysql_1  | 2020-08-26T20:00:27.792197Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.21)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
mysql_1  | 2020-08-26 20:00:28+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Temporary server stopped
mysql_1  |
mysql_1  | 2020-08-26 20:00:28+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: MySQL init process done. Ready for start up.
mysql_1  |
mysql_1  | 2020-08-26T20:00:28.931847Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.21) starting as process 1
mysql_1  | 2020-08-26T20:00:28.947655Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
mysql_1  | 2020-08-26T20:00:29.162873Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
mysql_1  | 2020-08-26T20:00:29.250374Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060, socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
mysql_1  | 2020-08-26T20:00:29.322041Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
mysql_1  | 2020-08-26T20:00:29.322181Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
mysql_1  | 2020-08-26T20:00:29.328435Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
mysql_1  | 2020-08-26T20:00:29.343021Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.21'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

**The problem**

Now that above is finished(Not sure if all is correct) I thought I would try and connect to it via mysql workbench but Im getting the following:

[image]

I also tried changing my binding address to :

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the compose file, under `ports:` you creating a forwarding rule from `localhost:3307` to `container:3307`.

While you can choose any source port that is not in use on your host machine, at the other end you **must** hit the port on which the container is listening: in this case it would be `3306`.

Your docker-compose.yml file should look like this:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:latest
    ports:
      - 3307:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: SomeRootPassword1!
      MYSQL_USER: someuser
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: Password1!
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wedding
```

...then you should be able to connect at `localhost:3307`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use docker internal network to bind address, instead of localhost (if you are not exposing the port), replacing `0.0.0.0` for `host.docker.internal`. This should do the trick.